# How do you activate a JS text animation when in view on a Carousel?

Tags: javascript

I'm sorry if this question has been asked before. I am very new to JS and have limited knowledge on it.

I have been trying to figure out how to activate the animation. With my code the animation loads at the same moment when the page is loading, i need to make it load when the content is in view. I have added an offset, but it didn't delay the animation but just not show it altogether.

```js
var slidetwo = new Array(
"Brief background of who had which children and who got married to who.", 
"- Include the Jewish year and the non - Jewish year ie BCE OR CE text two"
);
var Speed = 100; 
var Index = 0; 
var ArrLength = slidetwo[0].length; 
var ScrollAt = 20; 

var TextPos = 0; 
var Contents = ''; 
var Row; 

function typewriter2()
{
 Contents =  ' ';
 Row = Math.max(0, Index-ScrollAt);
 var destination = document.getElementById("unit-two-slide-two");

 while ( Row < Index ) {
  Contents += slidetwo[Row++] + '<br />';
 }
 destination.innerHTML = Contents + slidetwo[Index].substring(0, TextPos) + "_";
 if ( TextPos++ == ArrLength ) {
  TextPos = 0;
  Index++;
  if ( Index != slidetwo.length ) {
   ArrLength = slidetwo[Index].length;
   setTimeout("typewriter2()", 500);
  }
 } else {
  setTimeout("typewriter2()", Speed);
 }
}

$(function() {
$('#unit-two-slide-two').each(function(){
   $(this).waypoint(function() {
     $(this).addClass('show');
     }, {
       offset: '100px',
       horizontal: true
     });  
 });      
});


typewriter2();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="unit-221-1slide-top">
<p>After Yaakov received the blessings from his father, his brother Esav wanted to kill him. Yaakov forced to run away to the home of Lavan his uncle in Haran. Yaakov lived with Lavan for 22 years and married his two daughters and the two maid servants.</p>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<body>
  <div id="unit-two-slide-two"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `typewriter2();` to:

`$( "#unit-two-slide-two" ).load(typewriter2);`

This will trigger your function once the DOM has signaled it is loaded.

Comment: The animation doesn't seem to want to activate. I have two slides first one loads as normal when loading the page and second one nothing shows up (code above). The window max 800px wide and just off center to the screen, would this make a difference to the activation? p.s. thanks for the initial response

Comment: Yes im getting:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientHeight' of null
    at text-animation.js:43
text-animation-2.js:36 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at text-animation-2.js:36

Comment: It could be a jQuery-specific error. I've edited my answer. Try that and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I had no luck with that one either. 

Could it be this code where im going wrong, I copied it from someone else post hoping it would work so it may not be relevant:

$(function() {
$('#unit-two-slide-two').each(function(){
   $(this).waypoint(function() {
     $(this).addClass('show');
     }, {
       offset: '100px',
       horizontal: true
     });  
 });      
});

Comment: Yea, I think at this point you may need to refactor that section and see what's going on with your function scopes. Make sure `this` is pointing at what you think it is with a `console.log()`.

Comment: I have been experimenting with all sorts (amateur here) and having no luck. Do you know if theres another way I can activate the animation? I've been thinking of rebuilding the carousel but its so close to being finished I cant bring myself to do it and I will probably get to the same point.